# Is it possible to cap the addForce given without capping the max velocity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

Making a grapple hook swing game set in space (0 gravity) and I want the player to have some limited movement when floating without gravity (think of like weak boosters). I tried setting the velocity for the moving but then the momentum of the swing is lost so I've decided to use add force but the problem with that is there's no cap on the force so the "boosters" it ends up being really fast/powerful. If I cap the velocity as all the answers on here say then it'll cap the momentum from the grapple swing (core component) so I need a way to cap the actual force added but can't find a way to do that and Mathf.clamp doesn't seem to work with addForce.

Float movement code below:

```
    else if (!groundCheck)
                {
                    curSpeed = floatSpeed;
                    rBody.AddForce(new Vector2(Mathf.Lerp(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * curSpeed, 
                    0.8f), Mathf.Lerp(0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * curSpeed, 0.8f)));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

(I can't add a comment yet, I don't have enough points)

Did you try adding force in the opposite direction (like a air break)?